# Replace "&&" with "and" using re.sub in python.

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a string containing `&&`.
I want to replace all `&&` which have **SPACE** on both right and left side.

**Sample String**:

```
x&& &&&  && && x
```

**Desired Output**:

```
x&& &&&  and and x
```

**My Code**:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'\B&&\B','and','x&& &&&  && && x')
```

**My Output**

```
x&& and&  and and x
```

Please suggest me, how can I prevent `&&&` from getting replaced with `and&`.

Comment: This question gave rise to this question on HackerRank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/re-sub-regex-substitution/ Nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search using this lookaround regex:

```
(?<= )&&(?= )
```

and replace by `and`

**Code:**

```
p = re.compile(ur'(?<= )&&(?= )', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"x&& &&& && && x"

result = re.sub(p, "and", test_str)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX7wY0/5)

Comment: Thanks anubhava, It worked nicely for me. Can you please, share a little more about how this actually worked. It will help me a lot . Thanks ..

Comment: Yes sure. `(?<= )` is a positive lookbehind that makes sure `&&` is preceded by a space.  `(?= )` is a positive lookahead that makes sure `&&` is followed by a space.

Comment: This is very helpful knowledge! about regex... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex for this, just `split` will do this. ie, split your input string according to the spaces then iterate over each item in the list then make it to return `and` only if the item is equal to `&&` else return than particular item. Finally join the returned list  with spaces.

```
>>> s = 'x&& &&&  && && x'
>>> l = []
>>> for i in s.split():
    if i == '&&':
        l.append('and')
    else:
        l.append(i)


>>> ' '.join(l)
'x&& &&& and and x'
```

OR

```
>>> ' '.join(['and' if i == '&&' else i for i in s.split()])
'x&& &&& and and x'
```

Comment: `x&& &&&<space><space>and and x`-Desired Output
 
`x&& &&&<space>and and x` - Your Output

Your answer does not take care of multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1):

sample input

```
s = "x&& &&&  && && x"
```

you can use the lookbehind and lookhead assertion of regex

```
>>> print( re.sub(r"(?<=\s)&&(?=\s)", 'and',s))
x&& &&&   and   and  x
```

Here regular expression `(?<=\s)&&(?=\s)` means, && will be preceded and followed by space(\s).

**(?<=...)**

this is a **positive lookbehind assertion** which makes sure the matched string is preceded by **...**

For Example : (?<=x)abc will find a match in xabc

**(?=...)**

this is a **lookahead assertion** which make sure that matched string is followed by **...**

For example:  abc (?=xyz) will match 'abc ' only if it’s followed by 'xyz'.